# Confusing outputs with IMPORTXML & IMPORTHTML

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I just started with web scrape using Google sheet and would like to seek clarity on the issues below.

Here is the **screenshot** which will help to illustrate the issues:

[image]

**Formula used**

```
    A28 =IMPORTXML("https://www.thehuboug.com/collections/all?limit=100&sort=price+asc","//div[@class='grid__item small--one-half medium--one-half large--one-quarter']/a/@href")
    B28 =CONCATENATE("https://www.thehuboug.com",A28)
    C28 =IMPORTXML(B28,"//div[@class='grid__item large--one-half']/h1")
    D28 =TRANSPOSE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(B28,"table"),,2))
```

**Questions**

1. I couldn't figure out why C28 couldn't get the data but C29 has no issue with getting the data.
2. D28 is able to get the data but not for D29:D33
3. When I changed https -> http, I was able to get data for D34 and not C34. What does this mean?

Initially, when I first put in my formula, everything will be extracted accordingly. However, on the next day when I re-open the file again, I started to get results like this, with error *Resource at url not found*. If I copy the same formula on a new sheet, everything will work accordingly again. Overall, I am pretty confused about the behaviour here and would like to understand what can be improved to solve this.

Thanks in advance for helping me in this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A28:

```
=IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.thehuboug.com/collections/all?limit=100&sort=price+asc",
 "//div[@class='grid__item small--one-half medium--one-half large--one-quarter']/a/@href")
```

B28:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://www.thehuboug.com"&SUBSTITUTE(A28:A60, "/collections/all",, 1))
```

C28 and drag down:

```
=IMPORTXML(B28, "//div[@class='grid__item large--one-half']/h1")
```

D28 and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(B28, "table"),,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure I have the right understanding, can you help to provide some explanations about the change?

Comment: @user2832451 `/collections/all` needed to be excluded from url

Comment: Thanks for this! One last question, how do you determine `collections/all` was the reason?

Comment: I clicked on the generated link and noticed that url got redirected (corrected) eg. it didnt contained `collections/all`